# Regex with backslashes not working in preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the subdivision name (which sometimes can contain spaces) however I keep getting an error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I know my current regex does not support spaces which I also need help with but I think the backslash is whats breaking it in preg_match_all

```
$line = "WORK ORDERS\Subdivision Subdivision\Sec. 64\72751401_123 street dr.pdf"
$ptn2 = "/\\[a-zA-Z]+\\/";
preg_match_all($ptn2, $line, $matches2, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `\h` to match horizontal spaces.

```
$ptn2 = '~\\[a-zA-Z\h]+\\~';
preg_match_all($ptn2, $line, $matches2, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wG6zT4/1)

Comment: I got it to work with

$ptn2 = '/\\\\[a-zA-Z\h]+\\\\/';

Comment: Single quotes or double quotes should not be the problem here but the missing horizontal space. Without the space the regex would not match regardless of quotes.